# Dblink is not accepting the date format of postgressql

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I am extracting the data from other databases by using dblink but when i put the date condition it is showing below error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2019"
LINE 5:   where date(l.create_date)='2019-01-01'') 
                                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 562
```

```
select cus.* into cus_details from dblink('dbname=dbname user=admin password=admin123',
'select l.id,l.create_date,l.write_date,b.campaign
        from rb_lead l
         left join rb_campaign b on l.team=b.id 
        where date(l.create_date)='2019-01-01'')
as cus (id integer,create_date timestamp without time zone,write_date timestamp without time zone,campaign integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quotes inside your quoted string.

```
select cus.* into cus_details
from dblink(
    'dbname=dbname user=admin password=admin123',
    'select ... where date(l.create_date)='2019-01-01''
)
                                          ^
```

You'll need to escape the quotes around `2019-01-01` by doubling them.

```
select cus.* into cus_details
from dblink(
    'dbname=dbname user=admin password=admin123',
    'select ... where date(l.create_date)=''2019-01-01'''
)
```